# Is there an official name for using another module's import?

Tags: python, python-import

Imagine the following scenario:

A.py:

```
from B import func_b()
def func_a():
    print("rofl" + func_b())
```

B.py:

```
def func_b():
    print("copter")
```

main.py:

```
import A
A.func_a()
A.func_b()
```

Here `main.py` uses `func_b` via A's `import` of it. Note that `A.py` doesn't intentionally export the name via `__all__`, it simply exposes it as a consequence of how Python's namespaces work.

Subjectively, a lot of styleguides recommend not accessing `func_b` via `A`, but instead `importing B` directly and then using `B.func_b`, due to the increased coupling and violating the principle of data encapsulation.

Q: Is there an official name for this manner of round-a-bout importing?